# Angularjs Route Listener Doesn't Recognise Service Function

Tags: angularjs, service, routes

I've implemented a token based authentication system to my script. I have a simple service that checks if the user is logged on. And I use this service to check user status on every route change. Weird thing is; I can login just fine, and logout with no problems. But if I login again I get this error:

```
Error: AuthenticationService.isLogged is not a function
```

and as a result my logout function doesn't work. If I reload the page the error disappears and I can logout just fine.

Here is the log out function:

```
$scope.logout = function logout() {
            if (AuthenticationService.isLogged) {
                AuthenticationService.isLogged = false;
                localStorageService.remove('token');
                $location.path("/login");
            }
        }
```

And here is the route listener:

```
run(['AuthenticationService', '$rootScope', '$location', function(AuthenticationService, $rootScope, $location) {
    $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeStart", function(event, nextRoute, currentRoute) {
        if (nextRoute.access.requiredLogin && !AuthenticationService.isLogged()) {
            $location.path("/login");
            $scope.apply();
        }
    });
```

And the service;

```
module.factory('AuthenticationService', ['localStorageService', function(localStorageService) {
    var auth = {
        isLogged: function() {
            if (localStorageService.get('token')) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: AuthenticationService.isLogged = false <- there you are killing off the function, so when you try AuthenticationService.isLogged() it says it is not a function because it is 'false', just get rid of that part and it will work well

Comment: You are right! How did I miss it? I can try it tomorrow but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

A factory is supposed to return an object.

```
module.factory('AuthenticationService', ['localStorageService', function(localStorageService) {
        var auth = {
            isLogged: function() {
                if (localStorageService.get('token')) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        return auth;
        });
```

This should work and a good reading for factories, services, and providers can be found at http://tylermcginnis.com/angularjs-factory-vs-service-vs-provider/.

Comment: noticed it but thought he might have missed to type it in, wouldn't that make the first check cause an error?

Comment: You could be right, he also missed the closing ) for the factory and that should definitely throw syntax errors.

Comment: I believe it is caused by the AuthenticationService.isLogged = false, that way isLogged isn't a function on the next try

Comment: Yes sorry about that. I had very little time to post the question it seems I couldn't copy it properly. But Aboca pointed out the problem in the comments. Thank you very much for the resource you shared. I'll definitely read it word by word.

Answer (score 0):

Answer was provided in comments by Aboca. I quote;

"AuthenticationService.isLogged = false <- there you are killing off the function, so when you try AuthenticationService.isLogged() it says it is not a function because it is 'false', just get rid of that part and it will work well"

Thanks a lot!